# dynamically setting variables in html5 body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to dynamically set some of the contents of an html5 body with var strings defined in a JS.

below is what i have written so far and it doesnt seem to display the value specified.

```
<link href="src/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="src/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body> 

<script>
    var name = "John Smith";
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <button></button>
        <h1>New Claim</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
    <li> <p><h3>Your Name: <var>name</var></h3></p></li>

        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

i am trying to insert John Smith inside the "Your Name: text.

Thanks

Comment: You did not understand what the [`<var>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-var-element) is meant for. It's just a normal element, like `<code>` or `<span>`. It has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: `<h3>` is invalid inside of `<li>` and `<p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either give the VAR-Tag itself or it's wrapping LI-Tag an unique ID.

## In HTML

```
<li>
    <p>
          <h3>Your Name: <var id="name">name</var></h3>
    </p>
</li>
```

## JavaScript

```
var name = "John Smith";
$("#name").text(name);
```

### And by the way:

You shouldn't nest a Heading inside of a Paragraph, this doesn't make any sense.
Paragraphs are INLINE while Headings are BLOCKELEMENTS.

### [Check out this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2jyRk/)

Comment: paragraphs are block elements no? https://screenbud.com/shot/9587a29b-f3d1-4002-8dc2-6c29480ea7ce

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use JavaScript to "print" the contents of a variable, to the HTML-source. Here's an example:

```
<div id="test"></div>
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'This goes into the element!';
```

But since you're using jQuery, you could do this as well:

```
$('#test').text('This goes into the element!');
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like below. Have global JS variables assigned, reference them with a VAR html5 tag, use JS at the end of body (or after DOM load) to substitute the keys in the VAR tags with the values held in the global VARS object.

```
<script>
    VARS = {};
    VARS.name = "John Smith";
    VARS.age = 45;
</script>
...
Name : <var>name</var><br/>
Age : <var>age</var>
...
<script>
    // run once at end of body
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("var");
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
        var elm = all[i];
        var key = elm.innerHTML;
        if(VARS[key] != null)
            elm.innerHTML = VARS[key];
        else
            elm.innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The  tag isn't supposed to be used this way
Try this:

```
<link href="src/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="src/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body> 

<script>
    var name = "John Smith";

    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").text(name);
});

</script>


<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <button></button>
        <h1>New Claim</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
    <li> <p><h3>Your Name: <span id="name"></span></h3></p></li>

        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Edit: just to clarify one thing. The  tag isn't supposed to be used to hold the place to the value of a variable. It's correct semantic meaning is more to represent a mathematical variable or a programming variable when you are showing some code on your page. If I'm wrong here, please someone correct me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3").text("Your name : John Smith");
});
```

Add some classes on your divs, to easuly select the good tags